# Is it necessary to use `stackalloc` only in the same line you define the pointer to it?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe, stackalloc

In the following code:

```
unsafe
{
    int m = 10;
    int n = 10;
    double*[] a = new double*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        double* temp = stackalloc double[n];
        a[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to remove the superfluous variable `temp`?

The code:

```
a[i] = stackalloc double[n];
```

has compiler error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS8346  Conversion of a stackalloc expression of type 'double' to
>   type 'double*' is not possible.

Comment: Can you say how it fails?

Comment: @John it gets a compiler error.

Comment: That would be useful information to edit into your question - please do so and provide the exact error message.

Comment: The .net people recommend the use of `Span<double>` when working with `stackalloc` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc . I expect you'll be able to assign `a[i] = stackalloc ...` when a is of type `Span<double>[]`

Comment: this makes a nested array of 10 x 10 doubles?

Comment: @Confused y‌‌es __

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary to use `stackalloc` only in the same line you define the pointer to it?

Yes, this is necessary [according to the C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code).

Specifically, see the section on **Stack Allocation** which specifies the grammar as:

```
local_variable_initializer_unsafe
    : stackalloc_initializer
    ;

stackalloc_initializer
    : 'stackalloc' unmanaged_type '[' expression ']'
    ;
```

As you can see, you *must* use `local_variable_initializer_unsafe` with the `stackalloc_initializer`, which means that you must declare a local variable to initialise with the result of the `stackalloc`.

(Technically you can put as many line breaks into the statement as you like, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you were asking!)

Comment: @nano Yes, if someone asks a question in the title and a different one in the body, I'll usually answer according to the title because that's what people will usually see first when searching.